# How do we create sessions for Flutter the same way we create sessions for PHP?

Tags: mysql, flutter, session, dart, sharedpreferences

Hi I am working on a mobile application using Flutter and MySQL. I want to know how do I create a "session" where I can store the username, userID and pass it to the other screens.

Example,
if a user creates a post in the app, the user ID of the person logged in (as stored in "session") will be attached to the post.

I have done some research and found some sources about shared_preferences dependency, , but I'm still open to suggestions and advice.

Thank you very much, I really appreciate it

Comment: shared_preferences is the way to go brotha

Comment: or Hive for flutter, uses pure dart. the question is unclear, flutter is client side only, at bare minimum you can store them in a file and manage the session

Answer (score 0):

Check out [flutter_session](https://api.pub.dev/packages/flutter_session). The package adds user session support in Flutter and is easy to use.

```
// Store value to session
await FlutterSession().set("token", myJWTToken);

// Retrieve item from session
dynamic token = await FlutterSession().get("token");
```