# Can we work with PHP sessions in Flutter?

Tags: php, flutter, session

Can we work with PHP sessions with multiple PHP files in Flutter as normally sessions work with web. Dio package is not working like that. Want to know if there is anothor way of getting around.

Comment: I want to use server side events in my app. for that I need to modify stream accrording to user data. for that I want to use sessions as POST method is not working with SSEs.

Comment: This should answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/50299669/19168006 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/63066615/19168006